# How to force a title and text in the same page, and change the spacing accordingly?

Tags: spacing

The class file I'm using is from github https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV. I could not find a way to attach this class file. So, I put the link here. If anyone has a more convenient way to put the class file here, please let me know. Thanks.

The MWE is as follows

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}
\geometry{left=1.4cm, top=.8cm, right=1.4cm, bottom=1.8cm, footskip=.5cm}
\name{First}{Last}
\position{test}
\address{test}
\mobile{123}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\makecvheader[C]
\makecvfooter
  {\today}
  {Name}
  {\thepage}

\cvsection{Test 1}

\lipsum[1-7]

\cvsection{Test 2}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

The result I got is

page 1
[image]
page 2
[image]

1. Which package or command should I use to force the title and the text in the same page?
2. How to change the spacing in page 1 accordingly?

Comment: Don't use \maketitle.  It's supposed to be a convenience, not an obstacle.

Comment: With the standard `\section` command this never happens, unless you or the class you're using are doing something evil. Can you please make an example starting from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`?

Comment: you are asking people how to change your code without giving any indication at all what your current code looks like. latex never breaks the page after a section heading so if you get a page break after `section 1` there is an error in your code but impossible to guess what that is if you do not show it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your reply. I have put a MWE here. As I could not find a way to put the long class file here, I leave a github link here. I hope that would be useful.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your reply. I put the github link of the class file I'm using here since I don't know how to attach it. Hope this would be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't have picked that class it appears to have several issues, but a quick fix for the section command would be to add

```
\renewcommand{\cvsection}[1]{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionTopSkip}%%
  \sectionstyle{#1}%%
  \phantomsection
  \color{gray}\vhrulefill{0.9pt}%%
  \par\nopagebreak
}
```

Comment: This is indeed a quick fix. Also, your suggestion is right given that there is quite a lot of issues. Thanks for your help.